# includes method doesn't support type narrowing

Tags: typescript, include

##### What I am trying to do

shortens if condition using `includes` method.

##### card

```
const card = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Cyberpunk 2077",
  developers: ["Ian", "Joe", "Jack", "Smith"],
  author: "Denis",
  date: "October 11, 2022",
  release: "October 11, 2022",
  avatar: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/47313528?v=4",
  description: "The dark future in 2077",
  multiplayer: "2",
  singleplayer: "yes",
  languages: ["English", "Spanish", "German"],
  website: "https://cyberpunk.com",
  tags: ["action", "cyberpunk"],
  images: [
    "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9d/80/aa/9d80aafb807665611800cf6182a90790.jpg",
  ],
  download: "",
};
```

##### Original code

```
if (item === "developers" || item === "languages")
  return (
    <Row>
      <Item>{item}</Item>
      <Detail>
        {card[item].length > 1 ? card[item].join(", ") : card[item]}
      </Detail>
    </Row>
  );
```

##### Updated code

```
cosnt filteredKeys = ['developers', 'languages'];
```

```
if (filteredKeys.includes(item))
  return (
    <Row>
      <Item>{item}</Item>
      <Detail>
        {card[item].length > 1 ? card[item].join(", ") : card[item]}
      </Detail>
    </Row>
  );
```

##### Error on Updated code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBllB.jpg

```
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number | string[]'.
  Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can augment the `includes` method to do a type predicate as seen [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275#issuecomment-643376433)

```js
interface Array<T> {
  includes(searchElement: any, fromIndex?: number): searchElement is T;
}
```

Which will enable at least indexing of the data structure with your key, but it doesn't do exact type inference (you get a union of all the types of the object values)

Comment: Terminology issue: that's not a type assertion (`searchElement as T`), it's a type predicate (`searchElement is T`).

Comment: As for this suggestion, it's important to note that this is problematic as per [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275#issuecomment-702233949), since the mere fact that `searchElement` isn't present in an `Array<T>` doesn't mean that it's *not* a value of type `T` (e.g., `5` isn't in the `number[]` value `[1,2,3,4]` but it's still a `number`). This suggestion only works where `T` is a union of unit values and you know that every member of that union is in the array, which is hard to guarantee. So I'd avoid merging this in since it will have weird effects elsewhere.